# Data Recovery Help Ubuntu and WIndows

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, recovery

Okay so I was trying to backup files on my HDD. I took it out of my linux machine and put it into my windows machine. Windows said there was a problem with the drive and asked me if I wanted to run a scan. I clicked the two checkboxes: scan for an attempt recovery of bad sectors and fix file system errors. It was taking a long time so I canceled it, took the drive out of windows machines, put it back into linux machine to check it. SOme of my files are gone!!! what do i do??!!

Also, should I run a disc utility/data recovery like Ultimate Boot CD or TestDisk? I am thinking of called data recovery services but I don't want to screw something up.

Comment: Some things aren’t adding up here. Windows chkdsk, which is what runs when you scan for bad sectors and file system errors, does not support Linux volumes. So, it wouldn’t touch anything on the drive. One scenario that windows sometimes does is ask if you want to initialize a drive in which it doesn’t recognize, which would destroy all the data. So, I’m not convinced you are understanding the problem fully and what occurred. Are there NTFS volumes on this drive? Chkdsk also doesn’t erase files. In that rare case the file is already corrupt and what is left is moved to a folder named found.000.

Comment: @Appleoddity When I put the drive back into my Linux system some folders and files would not show up.  They are missing.  The drive is NTFS.  The files were accessible, then 10 minutes later after plugging it up to my windows machine and back into my Linux machine, they are missing/gone.  However, the drive still says it is about 50% full.  From what you say I am hoping it is just some sort of glitch?

Answer (score 0):

Use this [Software](https://www.easeus.com/datarecoverywizardpro) it is the best for recovering files. Don't use your HDD in the mean time or you will override files you want back.

```
Install a new HDD in your linux machine

Plug your used HDD with your missing files as a secondary to read
```

If you need a USB adapter, [Ebay one here](https://www.ebay.com.au/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1313.TR12.TRC2.A0.H0.Xusb%203.0%20to%20sata.TRS0&_nkw=usb%203.0%20to%20sata&_sacat=0)

Comment: Thanks.  I plugged the HDD up to my machine to look at files and that is when I discovered the missing data.  I then went onto the internet to research.  However, I saved nothing/wrote nothing to the HDD.  Will this effect data recovery even though I didn't saved anything to the drive?

Comment: Maybe, don't risk anything. It is your important data no one else's?

Comment: Yeah it is all mine

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you do is get a second hard drive and use (gnu) ddrescue from a pen drive (or equivalent,) to make a copy of your disk, ideally then doing another bitcopy to another drive.

This is important as it sounds like your HDD is dying. Trying to recover data off a failing disk is going to make it worse, so you want to get as much raw data as possible (which ddrescue excels at) and then recover from a good disk.

Once you have the raw data, the ideal is to work on a copy, so if your software fails you can try other techniques. There is lots of software recovery options available depending on the data type and filesystem. Things like recuva, photorec spring to mind.

Comment: Wow thanks.  Dying, though? It is brand new.  Been working fine for 5 months.

Comment: I've had hard drives die on me within hours of purchase (more then once) - HDDs are the most likely things to fail on a PC.  What does SMART tell you?

Comment: If the drive is dying, do you think it has anything to do with what I did earlier on windows?  also, this may sound like a dumb question, but what is SMART?

Comment: @Polymatheo SMART (Actually S.M.A.R.T) is technology built into (almost?) all SATA hard drives which try to predict failure and also advise what the drive thinks of itself.  If you Google it there are quite a few ways of pulling this data from the drive.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that.  Want do you think about what Appleoddity said?  Do you think running ultimate boot CD will damage or screw something up for data recovery services that I might call?  Did windows chkdsk really erase some data or am I wrong about my problem?

Comment: Appleoddity is a respected member of this forum and provides good answers. I dont consider myself more qualified then he is, but I dont know his grounds for stating that checkdisk does not erase data. Anything you do could potenyially make things worse. If your data is worth more then (nominally) $3k to you and you can afford it, find a reputable expert. If not get a couple of disks, use ddrescue to bitcopy your data, then copy the bitcopy and if the bitcopy works you get unlimited chances because you can revert to the current state.

Comment: There are only really 3 risks/ downsides to ddrescue - 1. You need to make absolutely sure you dont mix up source and target disks. If you are not familiar with Linux systems find a local to help and be super careful. 2. If the disk is failing, any read activity can make it worse, making a recovery firms job harder or impossible. 3. You need to get additional hard drives to attempt recovery.

Comment: Other thoughts: 1. Running a recovery disk on your raw corrupted system without a plan is high risk. DDRescue mitigates thus risk by backing up your disk as it is now. 2. The HDDs you need for it can be reused as a backup system so this does not happen again. 3. The big advantage of a data recovery service comes in if you have a hardware failure. Recovering from hardware failure really requires specialist tools which are hard to get (like clean room and doner drives).They also have knowledge you lack - but are the ambulance at the bottom if the cliff.

Comment: Also, getting S.M.A.R.T values (even if it requires a boot disk) is very low risk as - provided you do not kick off a disk test - S.M.A.R.T reads from the HDD firmware, not the platters, so it does not make things worse. Photorec will get you raw data back in a messy state and requires an additional disk. If you are sure you dont have HDD failure using it won't hurt as it dies not modify your disk, but the results will be poor/messy -  its a recovery tool of last resort. Have you read https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Advanced_NTFS_Boot_and_MFT_Repair its not the boot sector you worry about.